# Multiple Exponential Distributions, following each other

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I hope you're all doing well. I'm stuck on the logic for the following problem:

Person 1 and Person 2 are working independently on completing the same two chores, denoted $C_1$ and $C_2$. Each with starts with $C_1$, starting $C_2$ immediately upon completion of $C_1$. The times it takes Person 1 to complete the chores have exponential distributions with means $\mu_{11}$ and $\mu_{12}$ respectively, and the times it takes Person 2 to complete the chores have exponential distributions with means $\mu_{21}$ and $\mu_{22}$ respectively. Assuming all times are independent, find the probability Person 1 completes the tasks first.

I first went about this problem by considering the sum of the probabilities below
$$\begin{align} P(T_{11} < T_{12} < T_{21} < T_{22}) + P(T_{11} < T_{21} < T_{12} < T_{22}) + P(T_{11} < T_{21} < T_{12} < T_{22})\end{align}$$

However, I realize that this fails to consider that $T_{11}$ and $T_{12}$ don't overlap, (We consider $T_{11}$, and then $T_{12}$ commences after the end of $T_{11}$). Same goes for the other two times. Does anyone have suggestions for the logic here? Thanks in advance!